# Custom Vue Directive For v-bind

Tags: vue.js, vue-directives

I currently have something like this:

```
<q-input v-model="value" label="Some Label" v-bind="getDefaults('someId')" />
```

where `getDefaults()` is:

```
function getDefaults (id) {
  return {
      'id': id,
      'clearable': true,
      'lazy-rules': true,
      'outlined': true,
      'class': 'form-padding'
       // more props/parameters
   }
}
```

Now, I want to convert the v-bind to a custom directive.

````
export const sampleDirective = {
  inserted: function (el, binding) {
    // this doesn't work
    el.class += 'form-padding'
    // how to set id from here
    // and how to set the props as well (like ```clearable```, ```lazy-rules```, etc)?
  }
}
````

So how can I set these parameters/props from the custom directive so I can just call it like this:

```
<q-input v-model="value" label="Some Label" v-sampleDirective="{ id: 'someId' }" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html)

> Note that in Vue 2.0, the primary form of code reuse and abstraction is components - however there may be cases where you need some low-level DOM access on plain elements, and this is where custom directives would still be useful.

So one thing is clear, props are out of the question; you have to use default provided directives like `v-bind` as you cant access/change anything other than raw DOM element. the default provided directive works something different and at compiling the component to render function; where as custom directive works different and only allow to **modify** DOM element.

to be more clear directives like `v-if`, `v-else` are used in template converted to javascript `if-else` clause in render function where simillarly `v-for` converted to `for` loop in render function.

As the question of class, id and Other attributes of a DOM element you can modify those using native javascript DOM APIs like `element.classList.add("my-class")`, or `element.setAttribute('id', 'something')` etc.

Note: My personal opinion about naming `custom directive` leading to the confusion of some peoples including myself that `custom directive` are equivalent to vue's directives like `v-for` and can be constructed by API user, which is not the case.

TL DR;

Well you cant!